# Rails Active Storage: Direct upload from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am creating a sitemap for my website and I need to upload it to S3, because of Heroku temporary filesystem.

I have already configured Active Storage with Amazon S3 but I don't want to create a Model entity only for a single upload. Is there a way just to:

**sitemap.rb**

1. Upload the file generated "public/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz" to S3 with Active Storage
2. Retrieve the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong tool.

> Active Storage facilitates uploading files to a cloud storage service
>   like Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Microsoft Azure Storage and
>   attaching those files to Active Record objects.

ActiveStorage is built around attaching files to models. Trying to use it without a model will be very painful as you are working against the entire design of ActiveStorage.

If you just want to upload a file created on the server then use the [aws-sdk-ruby gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) instead.

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-west-2')
obj = s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('key')
obj.upload_file('/path/to/source/file', { acl: 'public-read' })
# Returns Public URL to the file
obj.public_url
```

See [upload an Object Using the AWS SDK for Ruby](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html).

Comment: Ok, make sense. How can I create a "public url" so that external resources like google can access it without expiration?

Comment: If not sure what you mean, that example returns the public url to the resource created on S3. If you want to have a fixed URL in your rails app that serves the resource you can just create a controller that redirects or proxies.

Comment: I tried to access the url generated but it says "AccessDenied".
URL: https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key
The file is correctly uploaded in file S3 bucket

Comment: Ah, you have to set the ACL. `obj.upload_file('/path/to/source/file', { acl: 'public-read' })`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html